# How to get code coverage for python using Bazel

Tags: bazel

I would like to generate a code coverage report for all of my python tests using Bazel. Currently I am using Bazel version 0.19.1, but I will be upgrading to 0.22.0 shortly. I found this open bug from 2017, that was worked on for a while, but communication on this page just suddenly dropped (https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/issues/43). Does anyone know where or not `bazel coverage` supports code coverage for py_tests and py_binaries?

Currently when I run the command `bazel coverage //path/to/python/tests/...`

```
(verb_py3) joshsullivan@VERB790-Linux:~/verb/test_folder1$ bazel coverage test_sub1/...
INFO: Using default value for --instrumentation_filter: "//test_folder1/test_sub1[/:]".
INFO: Override the above default with --instrumentation_filter
INFO: Build options have changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analysed 8 targets (2 packages loaded, 7612 targets configured).
INFO: Found 8 test targets...
FAIL: //test_folder1/test_sub1:tests_marked_test (see /home/joshsullivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joshsullivan/05ff476f42160380dc4701b6f3f01f26/execroot/verb/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/test_folder1/test_sub1/tests_marked_test/test.log)
ERROR: /home/joshsullivan/verb/test_folder1/test_sub1/BUILD:21:1: output 'test_folder1/test_sub1/tests_marked_test/coverage.dat' was not created
ERROR: /home/joshsullivan/verb/test_folder1/test_sub1/BUILD:21:1: not all outputs were created or valid
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.933s, Critical Path: 0.25s, Remote (0.00% of the time): [queue: 0.00%, setup: 0.00%, process: 0.00%]
INFO: 3 processes: 3 linux-sandbox.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
//test_folder1/test_sub1:buildifier_test__BUILD                       NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1:clang_format_test                            NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1:cpplint_test                                 NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1/tests:buildifier_test__BUILD                 NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1/tests:clang_format_test                      NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1/tests:cpplint_test                           NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1/tests:tests_marked_test                      NO STATUS
//test_folder1/test_sub1:tests_marked_test                               FAILED in 0.2s
  /home/joshsullivan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_joshsullivan/05ff476f42160380dc4701b6f3f01f26/execroot/verb/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/test_folder1/test_sub1/tests_marked_test/test.log

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

This provides me with blank coverage.dat files

I am looking for a way to use `bazel coverage` so that my tests will pass and a shared coverage.dat file will be generated with the combined coverage results of all tests that were ran. That way I can take the coverage.dat file and use that to generate an html report. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hello 
4 years ago.
you have to update to Bazel 6.0 better to get coverage.